# Error Missing Environment Variable en script con Python

Tags: python

en primer lugar disculpad mi desconocimiento, soy muy novato. Al tirar un pequeño script en python obtengo este error:

**ERROR: Missing 'keyword' Environment Variable**

Probablemente tenga fácil solución, pero mi escaso conocimiento no la alcanza.

Gracias!

Comment: Podrías colocar el código que tienes?

Comment: imagino que tendrá algo que ver con esto:

Comment: if 'keyword' not in os.environ:
    exit('ERROR: Missing \'keyword\' Environment Variable')

Comment: O_O pero si el error es clarísimo. Tu mismo lo estas generando!

Comment: Por cierto agrega eso a la pregunta. Todos los detalles importantes deben ir en la pregunta.